# Custom Dependency Injection for Sitecore pipeline processor with Ninject

Tags: pipelines, dependency-injection

I've implemented a custom Resolver for my Controllers for Ninject which works fine, however this is not working for pipelines.

How can I create a custom dependency Injection for Sitecore pipelines?

When I read the anwser below, I think I need to use Factory, but I am not understanding how this works.

I've the following class

```
public class RedirectResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    private IWasInjected _injection;

    public RedirectResolver(IWasInjected injection)
    {
        _injection = injection
    }

    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
         //Do Something
    }

  }
```

this Processor I've registered in the following pipeline

```
<pipelines>
  <httpRequestBegin>
    <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="MyNamespace.RedirectMapResolver, AssemblyName.Feature.Redirects" resolve="true">
    </processor>
  </httpRequestBegin>
</pipelines>
```

thats my current "Implementation" but I don't understand how I get the Factory explained in the blogpost https://cardinalcore.co.uk/2014/07/02/sitecore-pipelines-commands-using-ioc-containers/ to resolve my Injection?

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you on? And what have you tried so far that isn't working?

Comment: @DanSinclair Sitecore 9 Update 2 and I don't know really what to try, because I don't unterstand how this is working.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand about using a Factory the way Nat detailed in his blog?

Comment: Currently I've switched to use the service Locator anti Pattern until I understand the pipeline resolving right

Answer (score 0):

I have a talk on this :)

https://slides.com/gravypower/solid_sitecore_d#/15

Here is the supporting repo for that talk:

https://github.com/gravypower/SOLIDSitecore

You need to use `ref=` rather than `type=` and a factory adaptor as you suggest.

Also, I would consider a different DI framework Ninject is very slow, well it was.

Hope that helps, reach out to me on Sitecore Community Chat if you have any issues.

Good luck

Aaron

**Update:**

When you want to use this pattern (Container Adaptor Factory) with pipeline groups you need to use ref to a config node under types where you deny the ref and the factory it seems.

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <group groupName="layoutService">
          <types>
              <ExampleContextExtension ref="SitecoreJss.Examples.ExampleContextExtension, SitecoreJss.Examples" factory="FactoryContainerAdapter"/>
            </types>
        <pipelines>
          <getLayoutServiceContext>
            <processor ref="ExampleContextExtension">
              <AllowedConfigurations hint="list">
                <!-- Unless you change the Layout Service config used by your JSS app, this should always be present. -->
                <jss>jss</jss>
              </AllowedConfigurations>
              <Applications hint="list">
                <!-- Restrict the JSS apps for which this processor will execute. -->
                <reactApp>JssReactWeb</reactApp>
              </Applications>
              <Routes hint="list">
                <!-- Restrict the route items for which this processor will execute. IDs, item paths, and wildcard item paths are allowed. -->
                <services>/sitecore/content/JssReactWeb/Home/Services*</services>
                <portfolio>{BAD2C001-1746-4312-8422-B28806A1191E}</portfolio>
              </Routes>
            </processor>
          </getLayoutServiceContext>
        </pipelines>
      </group>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: yes I know Ninject is slow but I need to use it because of our dependent Nuget Packages which all use Ninject.

Comment: All good :), how did you go? I am keen to help you out as I love DI.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to resolve DI with the below piece of code:

`private static IWasInjected Injection => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IWasInjected>();`

I am updating your code here:

```
public class RedirectResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    private static IWasInjected Injection => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IWasInjected>();

    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
         //Do Something
    }
  }
```